# Не подключается к БД при запуске приложения на другом ПК?

Tags: oracle, golang

Написал программу, которая конектится к БД Oracle и выполняет `update`. На моем компе работает, на компе другого человека нет.

Что я не учел?

Ошибок никаких не возникает - приложение просто сворачивается после ввода данных.
На моем ПК приложение отрабатывает полностью.

Просто сделал `go build` на винде. Может кто подскажет, что можно сделать?

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    //_ "github.com/go-goracle/goracle"
    _ "gopkg.in/goracle.v2"
)


func main() {
    fmt.Print("Case 1:\n Update state_id,\n Case 2:\n Update Fn_Number\n\n")

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter Code: ")
    scanner.Scan()
    number := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Println("Code:", number)
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(number)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    switch i {
    case 1:
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Enter device_id: ")
        scanner.Scan()
        device_id := scanner.Text()
        scanner2 := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Enter device_state_id: ")
        scanner2.Scan()
        device_state_id := scanner2.Text()
        scanner3 := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Press enter for start update device_id: ", device_id, ", next state_id: ", device_state_id)
        scanner3.Scan()
        start := scanner3.Text()
        fmt.Println(start)
        db, err := sql.Open("goracle", "Здесь коннект к БД")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            log.Println(err.Error)

            return
        }
        defer db.Close()

        // start the transaction
        transx, err := db.Begin()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        rows := `update Ferma_Devices set device_state_id = ` + device_state_id + ` where device_id in ('` + device_id + `')`
        //commit;`

        fmt.Println(rows)

        rowsQuery, err := db.Query(rows)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error running query")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        // complete the transaction
        err = transx.Commit()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(".....Error Committing Transaction")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer rowsQuery.Close()

        time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)

        rows2 := `select device_id, device_state_id
        from Ferma_Devices
        where device_id ='` + device_id + `'`

        rowsQuery2, err := db.Query(rows2)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error running query")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer rowsQuery2.Close()

        var count int

        for rowsQuery2.Next() {
            var device_id string
            var device_state_id string

            errQuery := rowsQuery2.Scan(&device_id, &device_state_id)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(errQuery)
            }
            count++
            fmt.Println("Info: [ device_id: ", device_id, ", state_id: ", device_state_id, "]")
        }

    case 2:
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Enter device_id: ")
        scanner.Scan()
        device_id := scanner.Text()
        scanner2 := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Enter device_fn: ")
        scanner2.Scan()
        device_fn := scanner2.Text()
        scanner3 := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Press enter for start update device_id: ", device_id, ", next device_fn: ", device_fn)
        scanner3.Scan()
        start := scanner3.Text()
        fmt.Println(start)

        db, err := sql.Open("goracle", "Здесь коннект к БД")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            log.Println(err.Error)

            return
        }
        defer db.Close()

        // start the transaction
        transx, err := db.Begin()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)

        rows := `update Ferma_Devices set device_fn = '` + device_fn + `' where device_id = '` + device_id + `'`

        rowsQuery, err := db.Query(rows)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error running query")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer rowsQuery.Close()

        // complete the transaction
        err = transx.Commit()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(".....Error Committing Transaction")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        rows2 := `select device_id, device_fn from Ferma_Devices where device_id = '` + device_id + `'`

        rowsQuery2, err := db.Query(rows2)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error running query")
            fmt.Println(err.Error)
            return
        }
        defer rowsQuery2.Close()

        var count int

        for rowsQuery2.Next() {
            var device_id string
            var device_fn string

            errQuery := rowsQuery2.Scan(&device_id, &device_fn)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(errQuery)
            }
            count++
            fmt.Println("Info: [ device_id: ", device_id, ", device_fn: ", device_fn, "]")
        }
    }

    scanner2 := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Press enter for close")
    scanner2.Scan()
    end := scanner2.Text()
    fmt.Println(end)
}
```

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно, что именно не работает.  Добавьте в вопрос описания конкретных ошибок.

Comment: на другом пк стоит instant client нужной версии?

Comment: Нет - клиент никакой не стоит - просто когда писал подобную штуку для запросов к sql - все было ок

@Ainar-G просто приложение сворачивается после ввода данных

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что проблема в подключении? Вы же написали, что:  _Ошибок никаких не возникает - приложение просто сворачивается_. Или весь ваш код выполняет только подключение к БД?

Comment: @0xdb потому что сразу после ввода данных идет подключение к БД - залогировать не получилось - наверное что-то не так делаю - так как не программист,
а вообще просто предположил что на этапе подключения - сам не могу понять в чем проблема так как на моем ПК работает от и до без изъянов - возможно для оракла требуется что-то установить на компьютер, на котором данный exe файл запускается.

Код работает так - сначала выбирается один из кейсов - далее ввод данных под выбранный кейс - далее подключение к БД и выполнение скрипта

Comment: Вам надо установить на всех ПК, где вы запускаете программу, Oracle Instant Client. Почему нет сообшщений об ошибке, остаётся загадкой.

Comment: Спасибо - попробую
Интересно почему когда писал подобную вещь для sql скриптов все работало как надо

А как обычно делается при написании таких программ с установкой необходимого софта? файлы вкладываются просто в папку с основной программой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пакет [goracle](https://github.com/go-goracle/goracle) использует для подключения к БД Oracle OCI обёртку [ODPI-C](https://www.github.com/oracle/odpi).

> Although an Oracle client is NOT required for compiling, **it is at run time**.

Для компиляции Oracle клиент не требуется, но он необходим для подключения.
Загрузить его можно с [офф. сайта](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.htmlhttps://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html).

Подробнее о взаимодействии с Oracle клиентом, его установке и редистрибуции, [в документации к ODPI-C](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#id5).

Comment: Рад был помочь! Там не сложно, если что-то останется не понятно - спрашивайте.

Comment: И ещё, пожалуйаста возьмите на заметку, если в следующий раз будете задавать вопрос, не выкладывайте весь код в вопрос. Например, раз вы спрашиваете  про подключение, то создайте короткий, воиспроизводимый пример, где собственно только подключение и ничего более.

Comment: Хорошо, думал пример всей программы даст понимание что и как должно работать)

Comment: Как видите нет - больше понимания не дало, а кто-то  ещё и минус поставил иммено за портянку кода.